# All double integrals produce error

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am a beginner to the Mathematica community; however, for my Multivariable Calculus class I have made a number of double integrals that have worked successfully. Today, while working every single double integral I typed in (including retrying previously correct and functional ones) produces an error. All integrals I have tried have failed from simple to complex, but here is one example

`Integrate[x^2*y+3*x*y^2, {x, -Sqrt[8], Sqrt[8]}, {y, 0, (8-x^2)}]`
produces error
"Invalid integration variable or limit(s) in {x^3, 0, 1}"

Could someone please help me with this issue?

Comment: What is your Mathematica version?  If you use old version, maybe this  `Integrate[
 Integrate[x^2*y + 3*x*y^2, {y, 0, (8 - x^2)}], {x, -Sqrt[8], 
  Sqrt[8]}]`

Comment: I got it through my school, so I believe I have the most recent version. That script still produces the exact same error.

Comment: I can't reproduce any error. I am on MMA 12.0.0 on Win10-64.

Comment: As quickly as it came, the error is now completely gone. Perhaps a temporary software glitch?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because no one can reproduce the problem the OP is experiencing; I suspect it was being caused by corrupted lexical elements in the OP's Mathematica notebook.

Comment: It might be possible that your error message was caused because Mathematica keeps a cache history of previous assignments. For example, minutes or hours ago you did `x=2` and then forget all about that and later do `Integrate[3*x,{x,0,1}]` That looks like a simple integral to do, but Mathematica is thinking x has the value 2. instead of being a variable. That may not be exactly the source of your problem, but it might. Restarting Mathematica or reading and understanding the documentation and using `Clear` can make it remove that prior assignment. Keep that in mind when odd errors show up later

Comment: Your code runs normally with V12 + Win 10-64.

Comment: OK in 12.1.1.0 on Windows 10.